# How to hide my application's domain addresses?

Tags: android, dns

I have many domain addresses in my application and if I follow my application by using WireShark or NetGuard programs, my app's domain addresses are shown.

Appeared domain addresses from NetGuard:

```
e.crashlytics.com/443
myapp.com/443
myapp2.com/443
```

How can I hide these addresses programmatically?

Comment: you can't do that, as it is done on the network layer, which you can't influence on. If you really need it, you may want to use some implementation of VPN, or use a proxy connection in your app. That way you will see the intermediate server connections (Proxy server URL/IP address) in Wireshark, but not your real API address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no way you can hide these addresses if you are sending a request to them from your application.  What you can however do is use a proxy domain, and send requests to that domain from your application, and internally pipe data from the source domain through the proxy.  The call flow would be:

application -> proxy.com -> (e.crashlytics.com / myapp.com / myapp2.com, based on either a request header, or path)